# TikZ: shade plane with a colour gradient

Tags: tikz-pgf, gradient

I was wondering how I could shade this given plane:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [plane/.style={trapezium,draw,fill=red!80,trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,minimum height=1.5cm},scale=1.0]
    \node (p)[plane] at (0,0){.};
    \draw (p.center) edge ++(0,2cm) edge[densely dashed] (p.south) (p.south) edge ++(0,-1cm);
    \draw (-.25,-.125) node[above]{$P$} (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

from `white` at the Center `(0,0)` to `red!80` at the edges.

Comment: do you mean something like `inner color=white, outer color=red!80`? (pass this as an option for `plane/.style` instead of `fill=red!80`)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to add shading to your `plane`, the simplest way is to just set the `inner color` and `outer color` to its respective colours, instead of using `fill`, like so:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [plane/.style={trapezium,draw,inner color=white,outer color=red!80,trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,minimum height=1.5cm},scale=1.0]
    \node (p)[plane] at (0,0){.};
    \draw (p.center) edge ++(0,2cm) edge[densely dashed] (p.south) (p.south) edge ++(0,-1cm);
    \draw (-.25,-.125) node[above]{$P$} (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: shading]